# opening a dialog from a floating widget

Tags: android, android-widget, dialog

I'm trying to make a floating widget (service) which does the following:

on touch, movable - seems to work fine.

on click, opening a simple alert dialog box - not working.

code:

```
public class Service1 extends Service {

private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView serviceIcon;




@Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    serviceIcon = new ImageView(this);
     serviceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(serviceIcon, params);

     //making the icon movable
     serviceIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         private int initialX;
         private int initialY;
         private float initialTouchX;
         private float initialTouchY;

         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             switch (event.getAction()) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     initialX = params.x;
                     initialY = params.y;
                     initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                     initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                     return true;
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     return true;
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                     params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                     windowManager.updateViewLayout(serviceIcon, params);
                     return true;
             }
             return false;

         }
     });

     serviceIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (serviceIcon != null) windowManager.removeView(serviceIcon);
}

public void dialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setMessage("set message");
    alert.setTitle("set title");
    alert.setPositiveButton("positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alert.show();
}



}
```

i called the dialog method inside the setOnClickListener.

i did not forget the .show in my dialog method

What am i missing?

when i click the widget nothing happens. nothing pop and nothing crush, there is no error on the log. i do able to drag it though.

after commenting the onTouch method, in order to focus only at the onClickListener, i moved the dialog method to the main activity instead, and called it back inside the onClickListener, in order to try to fix the problem. now i get an error and i can show the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:150)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:110)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:452)
        at com.example.daniel.myproject.MainActivity.dialog(MainActivity.java:171)
        at com.example.daniel.myproject.Service1$1.onClick(Service1.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have  you tried showing the dialog from within an activity rather than directly from a service?

Comment: @hoomi Yes, i moved the dialog method into the MainActivity class, then called it back into the setOnClickListener, sadly, didn't work.

Comment: For test try calling `dialog()` directly in the `onStart()` of your service to see if the function actually shows the dialog

Comment: Also you are playing with the `onTouchListener`  and returning true for `MOVE_DOWN` and `MOVE_UP`. That will affect the behaviour of the `onClickListener`. Try commenting the `onTouchListener part and see if the `onClick` is working.

Comment: @hommi after checking what you have asked, both of them. i found that now i get pretty much the same exception, for both of those advice. 'Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application'

Comment: So it means before your dialog code was not being called and now is getting called. Try moving the dialog code to the activity. Then that should work

Comment: @hoomi As requested, i moved the dialog method into the activity, and call it again inside the onClickListener, while onTouchListener is commented. unfortunately i still get this exception: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Can you upload the whole stacktrace.